# How do I make this Ruby method more 'ruby-esque' - i.e. DRY and sleek?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.2

Consider:

```
def first_login?
    if (self.sign_in_count <= 20)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

It would be nice if I could just have it be 1 line of code...if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def first_login?
    self.sign_in_count <= 20
end
```

Your comparison already returns boolean value

You don't need `self` as well because methods are invoked on self implicitly

Answer (score 4):

Exactly one line :)

```
def first_login?
   sign_in_count <= 20
end
```